# Make sure method finishes prior to another method call

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a windows service that is consumed by several stations. When the service starts, I want to finish my `pre_process` task than begin my thread.

```
public class XML_Processor : ServiceBase
{
Thread worker;
bool running;

public bool Start()
{
            pre_process();// add files to queue, please ensure it completes first.
    bool success = true;
    running = true;
    worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ServiceLoop));
    worker.Start();

    return (success);
}

public bool Stop()
{
    // blah
}

public void ServiceLoop()
{
    string fileName;
    while (running)
    {
      // blah
```

I am not confident my code, I thought that the thread could be starting before pre_process() method.
Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: Does your `pre_process` method internally spawn any threads or tasks? If not, then its entire code would execute before your `worker` thread starts.

Comment: The pre_process method is simple.   FileInfo[] XMLFiles = di.GetFiles("*.xml");
            foreach (var fi in XMLFiles)
            {
                ProcessingQueue.Add(fi.FullName);
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be sure if your `PreProcess` method is done, then use an [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to signal the executing `Thread` to continue.

```
    private bool _running;
    private Thread worker;
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public bool Start()
    {
        // Make sure the reset event is in not signalled state
        _resetEvent.Reset();

        // Do you pre processing
        PreProcess();

        _running = true;

        worker = new Thread(ServiceLoop);
        worker.Start();

        return _running;
    }
```

In your `PreProcess` method you simply end with signalling

```
    private void PreProcess()
    {
        // Do pre processing stuff

        _resetEvent.Set();
    }
```

Your `ServiceLoop` "waits" until your `PreProcess` method signals to start

```
    public void ServiceLoop()
    {
        // Guaranteed nothing else will be executed until 
        // the reset event is signalled
        _resetEvent.WaitOne(); 

        while (_running) { /* .. */ }
    }
```

Comment: But what if the calls in the `PreProcess()` methods are spawned new threads? The `_resetEvent.Set();` only relates to the Main thread.

Comment: I didn't see it and if so, why do we need AutoResetEvent here?

Comment: bas, I have a follow up question, actually I have a parameter to pass into pre_process. I have to execute it several times. Such as pre_process(s1);pre_process(s2);pre_process(s3) etc, then the main thread begins. In this case, how about the code?

Comment: I'd pull out the event.set method into the `Start` method. Surrounding the PreProcess(s1)...PreProcess(s3) with the reset and set calls.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any ambiguity as to the current running threads in your process, you can always test the number of current threads so that you will be able to start your service ***only*** when the Main thread is alive without any other spawned running threads:

```
while(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads > 1);
worker.Start();
```

Comment: That limits your to ever create another background thread throughout your application

Comment: @bas How do I creating another background thread in my code example?

Comment: Didn't say that, merely pointed out that this "design" would not hold long

Answer (score 0):

is `pre_process();` a synchronous operation or asynchronous?
you need to make sure that all calls by the `pre_process();` method are synchronous.
if so the method is also synchronous and it will return only after finishing. if there are asynchronous operations you must wait for those to finish.

Comment: Please see my comment upstairs.

Comment: @Love we cannot do your work for you. if there are sub calls you are not sure that they are synchronous Google those.